# Can't get ajaxStop() / ajaxComplete() to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JS function:

```
function getInfo(s,n) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'includes/stock_summary.php',
        timeout : 10000,
        data : {
            s : s
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        function IsJsonString(str) {
            try {
                JSON.parse(str);
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Unable to communicate with Yahoo! Finance servers. Please try again later.");
            }
            return true;
        }
            $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : "includes/stock_desc.php",
            data : {
                s : s
            }
        })
        .done(function(desc) {
            $('#desc').html(desc);
        })
        if(data.change.charAt(0) == '+') {
            $('#change').css('color','#090');
            $('#puPrc').html('<img src="images/pu_prc_up.png">&nbsp;');
        }
        if(data.change.charAt(0) == '-') {
            $('#change').css('color','#D90000');
            $('#puPrc').html('<img src="images/pu_prc_dwn.png">&nbsp;');
        }
        var ask = data.ask+" <small>x "+data.askSize+"</small>";
        var bid = data.bid+" <small>x "+data.bidSize+"</small>";
        var change = data.change+" ("+data.changePc+")";
        $('#ask').html(ask);
        $('#lt').html(data.lastTrade);
        $('#ytd').html(data.ytdReturn);
        $('#bid').html(bid);
        $('#dayHigh').html(data.dayHigh);
        $('#dayLow').html(data.dayLow);
        $('#prevClose').html(data.prevClose);
        $('#vol').html(data.vol);
        $('#yearHigh').html(data.yearHigh);
        $('#yearLow').html(data.yearLow);
        $('#change').html(change);
        $('#stockName').html(n);
        $('#sym').html(s.toUpperCase());
        $('#open').html(data.sOpen);
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
        alert("Unable to communicate with Yahoo! Finance servers. Please try again later.");
    })

    $('#chart').html("<img src='http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s="+s+"&t=3m&q=l&l=on&z=m'>");
    $('.popUp').bPopup();
}
```

It is called using onClick().

The function itself does the job correctly but I only want to trigger the line:

```
$('.popUp').bPopup();
```

when everything else has finished.

I have used `$.ajaxStop()`, `$(document).ajaxStop()`, `$.ajaxComplete()` and `$(document).ajaxComplete()`

I have tried them inside, outside, above and below the function but cannot seem to get it to do what I need it to!

The only time it has worked is outside the function but it then runs on page load, which I obviously don't want to happen. I only want it to run when the function completes.

If someone could help me out with this pickle, please help!

Comment: have you tried in success function?

Comment: You've not shown us within your code how you tried to use ajaxStop event.

Comment: Please note ajaxStop, ajaxError, ajaxComplete are global ajax events, so they will fire for each and every ajax request on page. So this is not the best solution, so you need to append $('.popUp').bPopup(); to all possible cases of ajax chaining.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to answer your question.  Both the **.done()** and **.fail()** functions are unterminated (need semi-colons).  Can you fix that and see if anything changes?  The easiest thing to do when you are at a place like this is to start stripping code out of your page until it does work.  Then just add it back in until you find the faulty bit of code.  You say the **bPopup()** works outside of this function.  This is saying that there is a fail inside **this** function.  For instance, make onClick just run **bPopup()** and nothing else.  Hope that leads to something.  c0p

Comment: Ok, so I fixed it... @EhsanSajjad was completely correct. I put the bpopup function inside `success:` and it works perfectly. :) Thanks everyone

Comment: Oh,, and the reason it was called on page load is because the page was loaded using a `load()` method!

Comment: glad that its solved for you @matt1985..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one ajax call you want to add a `.always` handler that will execute when all the `.done` and `.fail` handlers have completed.

```
.always(function() {
    $('.popUp').bPopup();
});
```

If you have more than one ajax call on your page and you want the code to be fired once all the calls are completed then use the `ajaxStop` event.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('ajaxStop', function() {
        $('.popUp').bPopup();
    });
});
```